# Hide fields on the user update form

Tags: entities, users

In dutch, postal codes are formed by four numbers and two letters, e.g., 1274EA. I want to split this info to a field that contains '1274' and another field that contains 'EA' in this case. Can I do this by creating two hidden user fields, or should I create a new entity type with a user reference field and the two fields? I prefer the first option, if possible. CSS is no option.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. What is the purpose of having two separated fields? Would the users enter the postal code into those fields, or are they going to insert the postal code into a single field?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Postal Code](http://drupal.org/project/postal_code) module?

It seems to support dutch postal codes as well.